# Can COMMA be replaced with AND between two adjectives?

Tags: adjectives, punctuation

Can I replace the COMMA with AND in the following sentence?

**He was a difficult, stubborn child.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the sentence

> He was a difficult and  stubborn child.

would be grammatical. The first form with the comma is probably more common. There is no significant difference in meaning.

Comment: Thanks! one of my friends told me that using a comma makes sentences more formal. Is that true?

Comment: @Jelly_Fish It is arguable both ways and could depend on context. For what it's worth, I have written many formal papers and I would never use __and__ in this case, however, in general I would not expect someone to consider one or the other **more formal**.

Comment: @Jelly_Fish  Both forms are valid.  I agree with Eli Harold that neither can be picked out as "more formal". Which to use  is a matter of style.